# Why is "target" too short when using cealign in PyMOL?

Tags: pymol

Specifically, when runnning

```py
fetch 2mi1 3zkt
cealign 2mi1, 3zkt
```

I get the following error:

```py
CEalign-Error: Your target selection is too short.
```

If I look at the relevant file (`fitting.py`) in the P[yMOL github repo,](https://github.com/schrodinger/pymol-open-source/blob/master/modules/pymol/fitting.py) , it looks like it thinks there are no coordinates for atoms in the structure? Unfortunately the [documentation](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Cealign) doesn't really explain well (enough for me to understand) what needs to be selected, but I was under the impression that the example given uses a similar approach as I tried:

```
fetch 1c0mB 1bco, async=0
as ribbon
cealign 1bco, 1c0mB, object=aln
```

I have also tried with the `async=0`, and tried selecting single alpha carbons to use as `Target` and `Mobile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cealign` method is set to have a default [window of 8](https://github.com/schrodinger/pymol-open-source/blob/master/modules/pymol/fitting.py#L27-L29). It will throw [your error](https://github.com/schrodinger/pymol-open-source/blob/master/modules/pymol/fitting.py#L81-L82) if the target/mobile length is shorter than 2*window.

You can force the window size to be minimal; the minimum allowed is 3:

```
fetch 2mi1 3zkt
cealign 2mi1, 3zkt, window=3
```

Be careful, as the CE algorithm is very sensitive to these small window sizes, and the resulting alignments may vary a lot.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot.